# Using elementree, lxml - the only (.//) wildcard works for findall - cannot use relative paths?

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml, elementtree

I have a highly nested and long xml file that I need to parse and get into a pandas DataFrame.

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE PPP
  SYSTEM 'PPP.DTD'>
<book chg="R" model="AB" >
    <chapter chapnbr="09" chg="U" key="EN49" >
        <effect effrg="Afcd"/>
        <title>HOW TO WIN</title>
        <section chapnbr="09" chg="U" key="Edff" revdate="20100701" sectnbr="102">
            <title>What a start</title>
            <subject chapnbr="09" chg="U" key="Edff" revdate="20100701" sectnbr="102" subjnbr="00">
                <title>1.A</title>
                <pgblk chapnbr="09" chg="U" confnbr="00" key="Edff00" pgblknbr="00" revdate="20200701" sectnbr="102" subjnbr="00">
                    <effect effrg="12"/>
                    <title>1.A.i) Plan Ahead for the worst</title>
                    <prclist1>
                        <prcitem1 adns-numbering="8" adns-title="learning my way with help of good people" >
                            <effect effrg="Edff"/>
                            <prcitem asFragment="true">
                                <title>1.A.i) Plan Ahead for the worst</title>
                                <para>It was a cold January night, and I had too much whisky. 
                                    <refblock>
                                        09-102-00
                                        <refint rrr="22,445,555,555,555" refid="Edff0898">
                                            <effect effrg="Edff0899"/>
                                            0910200</refint>
                                    </refblock>. </para>
                                <para>In more usual circumstances, I possesed the self-control. Not this time 
                                    <refblock>
                                        09-102-00-1111
                                        <refint rrr="sdf,2323,2323" refid="Edff123">
                                            <effect effrg="Edff12434"/>
                                            09-102-00</refint>
                                    </refblock>. </para>
                            </prcitem>
                        </prcitem1>
                    </prclist1>
                </pgblk>
            </subject>
        </section>
    </chapter>
</book>
```

For a reason unknown to me, I cannot extract using relative XPath. Only `findall('.//')` works, but of course that outputs the complete file.

At a high level, I can get the xml parsed

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
```

I am also able to get the absolute paths for each element:

```
for e in root.iter():
    print(tree.getpath(e))
```

which gives (below is a sample, my actual xml is more nested and outputs x3 times the paths below):

```
/book
/book/chapter
/book/chapter/effect
/book/chapter/title
/book/chapter/section
/book/chapter/section/title
/book/chapter/section/subject
```

I then need to extract both tags and text from specific areas of the xml

However, if trying to use either absolute or relative path, the dictionary output, `d`, remains empty.

```
d={}

for item in root.findall('./section/title'): 
    d[item.tag] = item.text
```

same for

```
findall('.//section/title')
```

and again, empty dict for

```
findall('/book/chapter/section/title')
```

The only xpath that does work is:

```
findall('.//')
```

Comment: You might want to show (a part of) your xml file as sample. Are you using xml namespaces?

Comment: (1) You have to include your XML to get the best help.  (2) Your use of the terms *absolute* and *relative* is off:  `.//` and `./` are both relative; `/` and `//` are both absolute.

Comment: @AdrianW not using namespaces

Comment: @kjhughes thanks for pointing that out. I have also now included my xml sample.

Comment: Both `./book/chapter/section/title` and `.//title` should work with `findall()` to select `title` elements.   It would appear that `.//section/title` ought to have found at least one `title` too, despite your report.  Re-check?

Comment: Thanks all. It doesn't work for me. I could live with getting the complete xml into a pandas DataFrame, I will try that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findall()` does not accept absolute path names. You need relative path names.

`'.//section/title'` does work, but it returns `title` tags. So, no matter how many matches there are, you will end up with one single key named `title` in your dict, why may be not what you want.

If you want to use the title as index to the chapter, you could do like this:

```
d = dict((item.text, item.getparent()) for item in root.findall('.//section/title'))
```

From your sample XML, this creates a dict with key `What a start` and the chapter element as value.

If you want to use the full power of XPath expressions, I would recommend to use `XPathEvaluator`:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse('file.xml')

xev = etree.XPathEvaluator(tree)

d = dict((item.text, item.getparent()) for item in xev('/book/chapter/section/title'))

for k, v in d.items():
    print(f"{k} -> {v.tag}")
```

Output:

```
What a start -> section
```

Comment: many thanks. This is very helpful. It is still not clear to me on how to get to a "great great grandchild" element without stepping down through each level by specifying ('/a/b/c/d/e') ?

Comment: I have not managed to get into an specific node using XPathEvaluator and '//' and have managed to replicate using different source xml files. Trouble I now have is iterating through a folder of xml files. For some reason, no file is found

Comment: These seem to be two very different problems. For the first, have a look at [XPath 1.0](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xpath-19991116/) to learn more about the capabilities of XPath. You could create a new XPathEvaluator from any element as new starting point and navigate from there. There are axis specifiers like `descendant-or-self::`. So, really many possibilities. Not clear what is really your problem here. Simply iterating the children could be a solution too, depending on what you want to do. May be ask a new question for that. For the second, that should be feasible with `os.walk()`.

Comment: thank you. I have asked a new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/65799851/13607357