# Code using lxml and xpath works on single xml file, but fails when this is extended to a collection of similar xml

Tags: python, pandas, xpath, lxml

When parsing a single xml file to find a specific named node and it's text, I can get output as desired. However, I need to extend this code to a collection of xml files. When I do so, I get no output.

Here is my code on a single xml file, which works as desired:

```
from lxml import etree

parsed_single = etree.parse('Downloads/one_file.xml')

xp_eval =etree.XPathEvaluator(parsed_single) 

d = dict((item.text, item.tag) for item in xp_eval('//node_of_interest'))
```

The above code outputs the following, as expected:

```
d=
{'interesting text': 'Node_of_interest',
 'more inter text': 'Node_of_interest',
 'yet more txt': 'Node_of_interest'}
```

However, when applying the above code file by file to a folder of very similar xml files, my dictionary is empty. Here is the code attempt at parsing a collection of xml files:

```
import glob
import os

path = '/Users/Downloads/XML_FOLDER/'
read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, '*.xml'))

for file in read_files:
    
    file_pars = etree.parse(file)

    xpatheval = etree.XPathEvaluator(file_pars)

    full_dict = dict((item.text, item.tag) for item in xpatheval('//node_of_interest'))
```

Unfortunately, full_dict = {}

Comment: `full_dict` is rewritten from scratch in each iteration. So, the final contents will be that of the last loop. Declare `full_dict = dict()` before the loop and update with `full_dict.update(...)` inside the loop. [update](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update) accepts an iterable yielding tuples as argument. So, you can use the existing generator expression to provide the values, i.e. write `full_dict.update((item.text, item.tag) for item in xpatheval('//node_of_interest'))`

Comment: @AdrianW thank you once again. I have resolved this based upon your guidance. Cheers